# Delphi Community Edition - How to "force-close" an app with an other app

Tags: android, delphi

With ADB, it is possible to force stop an application by its package name:

```
adb shell am force-stop com.the.package.name
```

I want to do the same thing in an application. I have tried this code, but the result is not correct:

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes, Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText, Androidapi.JNI.App, Androidapi.Helpers;
 
procedure Kill;
var
  LService: JObject;
begin
  LService := TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
  if LService <> nil then
    TJActivityManager.Wrap(TAndroidHelper.JObjectToID(LService)).killBackgroundProcesses(StringToJString('com.the.package.name'));
end;
```

1. By using Android's `PackageManager` class, is there a chance to do this?
2. is it possible to simulate the same ADB command inside of an app?

Comment: I expect it's not possible. Why do you need to kill another app?

Comment: Did you enable the `KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES` permission in your app manifest before trying to call `killBackgroundProcesses()`?

Comment: Another option is [`Process.killProcess()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process#killProcess(int)), though that will only work if you are killing a process that is related to your app.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes I have added the permissons into app manifest and I'm able to kill BackgroundProcesses but this is not like the app "force stop" and I have some side effects when I restart this app after.

Comment: I'm able to start the application like this:  `code` Intent := TJIntent.Create;
Intent.setPackage(StringToJString('com.the.package.name'));
Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_MAIN);
SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);`code`

Comment: So, I know the "intent" so, possible to use Process.killProcess() ? Do you have some examples of this function in Delphi language ?

Comment: @RemyLebeau any chance to help me ?

Comment: @DaveNottage I don't want to kill but to force stop (as the action into the app menu) !

Comment: There is no public API to "force stop" an app.  Your only option is to request the app to stop itself, or to kill it. To get the process ID of the activity started by `startActivity()`, you will likely have to use `ActivityManager` to enumerate running processes until you find the one you want.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm able to kill the process like this:

Comment: `code`LService := TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
begin
if LService <> nil then
TJActivityManager.Wrap(TAndroidHelper.JObjectToID(LService)).killBackgroundProcesses(StringToJString('com.whateverpackagename.itis'));
end;`code`

Comment: But the app doesn't appreciate this command !

Comment: @RemyLebeau, do you have an example about your method to kill an app ?

Comment: @RemyLebeau and an other example to request the app to stop itself ?